# How to display user's fb profile pic in another project using django

Tags: python, django, facebook

Working on django project in which i have to implement facebook login functionality, i have implemented fb login successfully, but now what i need to do is to upload user's fb image in my proejct, i got user's fb image url using this:-

```
url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture'.format(request.POST['id'])
```

and got this url finally

```
http://graph.facebook.com/1209634319115496/picture
```

When i run above url in browser if displays user's fb profile pic, I want to know that should i upload this pic in my project's directory or should i save this url in database and run directly this url in

```
<img src="this url" >
```

so that every time if user changes its profile pic in fb, it will also reflect on my project.

Or if i should upload this pic in my project's directory, then how to upload image in django directory using url.

Comment: It is better to save the URL in your database as you have rightly pointed out that it will automatically reflect new profile pic.

Comment: are you sure, because i don't know that if user changes it's profile pic in fb so will this url be changed or it would remain same

Comment: Yes, the parameter after graph.facebook.com/ is actually facebook user id. So if you change your image the URL will still remain the same

Comment: Ok I save it in db, Thanks :)

Comment: @ManasviBatra +1 from me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to save fb image URL in your database because facebook image URL follows this pattern: "graph.facebook.com/fb_user_id/picture".

So even after you change your profile picture, the URL remains the same and hence you always get the latest image of the user.